# Is there a way to for kableExtra to use use the entire RStudio window?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, kable

I have a simple regression table with many columns in RStudio. I am using `modelsummary` to construct it, which yields a table to be constructed by `kable`.

But in my case the table is not using the full space in RStudio's Markdown editor to display the values. Is there a simple fix? This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You might have a better chance of getting an answer by supplying a Minimal Working Example, that is, a simple example with actually working code. Here is one: `kableExtra::kable_styling(kableExtra::kbl(cbind(mtcars, mtcars)))`. Notice that if you "knit" the document the resulting HTML table is *not* cut off. This implies that the issue is *unrelated* to `kableExtra` or `modelsummary`. It is a question specifically about RStudio's interface. Unfortunately, I could not find an obvious solution by skimming the RStudio preferences menu, but I may have missed it.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for your help and time both here and on Twitter!

Comment: I asked a similar question on the RStudio community forum and received no answers.  I think this is an RStudio issue rather than an R / kable issue.  It has to do with the size of the html box in RStudio.  https://community.rstudio.com/t/increase-dimensions-of-html-box-in-chunk-output/133555